# UBUNTU 19.10, black screen instead of login screen

Tags: login, password, 19.10

After trying to remove a normal user password ([as I explain here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215549/updated-help-how-to-disable-normal-user-password-at-lockscreen-with-black-scre/)) the pc just shows a black screen instead of the usual choose user to login with when starting the laptop.
Version of Ubuntu 19.10

Could it be it was related to the option of direct access without password left checked?

And how can I solved this?

Please, bear with me and [read the other question, my answer and my updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215549/updated-help-how-to-disable-normal-user-password-at-lockscreen-with-black-scre/), as I explain what I did to try to undo this mess (I had added this issue details in there because there was a 40 min limits before posting another question on askubuntu).

Sorry for my convoluted posts.

---

Atleast I can use that pc shared printer...

Answer (score 0):

Even after being able to get to the normal-user desktop (by sheer luck) and unchecking Automatic Access this issue wasn't resolved at all.

After rebooting I wasn't able to reach normal-user desktop again with the [same steps I described](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215549/updated-help-how-to-disable-normal-user-password-at-lockscreen-with-black-scre/) (who knows what sheer luck logged me in with Ctrl + Alt + F1 / F2 / Canc)

So I tried to login in Recovery Mode, got to the # prompt to login (as [answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/439488/) in this other Black Screen issue) and ran `startx`.

It worked! **BUT** after rebooting I got the same black screen and I couldn't login from # prompt because it told me something like "failed to boot"

Then I was able to login only when from Recovery I chose

```
dpkg       Repair damaged packages
```

and then reboot.

It tok more time than usual, but it booted up, and to be sure I even launched Software Updates and everything is smooth now